# subtract 1 week from current date - javascript

Tags: javascript

This is how I am getting current date, dd-MMM-yyyy format. How do I subtract 1 week.

```
    var m_names = new Array("JAN", "FEB", "MAR",
            "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC");

    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth();
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var current = curr_date + "-" + m_names[curr_month] + "-" + curr_year;
```

Comment: instead of another DIY, you might want to consider http://momentjs.com/ as library if you have more to do with dates than just this single example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);` after your `var d = new Date();`

```
 var m_names = new Array("JAN", "FEB", "MAR",
     "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC");
 var d = new Date();
 d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);
 var curr_date = d.getDate();
 var curr_month = d.getMonth();
 var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
 var current = curr_date + "-" + m_names[curr_month] + "-" + curr_year;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4GrKJ/)**

Answer (score 5):

You may try like this:-

```
var d= new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);
```

Using [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) you can do like this:

```
Date.parse("t - 7 d").toString("MM-dd-yyyy");     
Date.today().addDays(-7).toString("MM-dd-yyyy");  
Date.today().addWeeks(-1).toString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 3):

With [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), given that

```
moment().calendar();
```

is

```
Today at 10:27 AM
```

then all you need is

```
moment().subtract('days', 7).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
```

which becomes

```
06-Nov-2013
```

Answer (score 0):

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is awesome for relative date stuff like this:

```
var one_week_ago = moment().subtract('weeks', 1).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to sum or subtract from the date's elements, all you need to do is:

```
let currentDate = new Date()
//get each element from the current date
let year = currentDate.getFullYear()
let month = currentDate.getMonth()
let day = currentDate.getDate()
let hours = currentDate.getHours()
let minutes = currentDate.getMinutes()
let seconds = currentDate.getSeconds()
let milliseconds = currentDate.getMilliseconds()


//build the new date according the changes you want to do
let newDate = new Date(year, month, day - 7, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds )
console.log(newDate.toISOString())
```

The great thing about it is that even if the numbers are not "valid" for each parameter, the method will adjust it correctly, for example, if the number of the month is 13, another year will be added to the date and the month will be 1.

Answer (score -1):

Using [`date-fns`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns/v/latest),

```js
import { format, subDays } from 'date-fns';

console.log(format(subDays(new Date(),7), 'dd-MMM-yyyy')); // 18-Oct-2023
```